# Visual Basic Form not updating to current design

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm using visual basic 2008. My form is quite simple, with a few buttons and a few labels. Then I added a few more things, such as more buttons or more labels. These new elements show up in the design window, but they don't show when I debug the program. Debugging the program only brings up an older version of the program without the new elements. Screenshots:

[Design window (what should show up when debugging)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AIyp.jpg)

[What actually shows when debugging (an older version of the program)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxuGp.jpg)

Any help with this annoying issue is appreciated.

Comment: try rebuilding the program...

Comment: I've already tried building and rebuilding the program. Neither work.

Comment: What happens if you delete the `bin` and `obj` directories in your project and then rebuild?

Comment: @Dai That did it. Thanks